# Comparing dates across international dateline in javascript/moment

Tags: javascript, momentjs

So I have a server in NYC.  As part of an API response, it sends the current dateTime of **Friday 04:00PM** to a user who's local time is in India where it is currently **Saturday 01:30AM**.

How can I compare just the date portion and show that these are in fact the same "day"?  I have a requirement to show a "Register Now" button the day that registration opens with respect to the server's time (where registration processing will occur).

If I use moment.startOf('day'), will that return the same day regardless of timezone?

Comment: Internally, dates are always based on zone-independent timestamps. You can use something like `.startOf()` or zero out the time fields with the plain Date API and then compare the timestamps.

Comment: Note that if you're sending the client the date as a string formatted in local NYC time, the client, without code to compensate, will interpret that in the *client's* local time.

Comment: No, the output of [`startOf('day')`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/) takes in account timezone and it will return the start of the day for local time. If you have to deal with multiple timezone consider using [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) (momentjs manages only local time and utc, see [`moment.utc`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/))